# Return object from class function call

Tags: python, oop, object

I currently have two calls to a class, like so.

```
first_partition = Partition(samplename='Sample1', nS=5)
second_partition = Partition(samplename='Sample2', nS=6, batchname = 'Batch1', nB=4).
```

Since the partition class takes in a variable number of arguments, in my init, I have:

```
class Partition:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

What I want is to have first_partition and second_partition to return an instance of the partition object with two instance variables - k and n - that depend on the inputs I call.

I have a separate class method that tries to do that:

```
def pobject(self):
    nargin = len(self.__dict__)
    # Return default object if no arguments
    if nargin == 0:
        self.n = 3
        self.k = 0
        return self.n, self.j
    else if nargin == 2:
        self.n = 0
        self.k = self.nS + 1
        return self.n, self.j
```

But to return k and n, I have to do:

```
first_partition = Partition(samplename='Sample1', nS=5)
print(first_partition.pobject())
```

What I want is the first line to return something when I call

```
first_partition = Partition(samplename='Sample1', nS=5)
```

I know `def __init__` can't return anything and so I tried `def __new__` instead of def pobject but it doesn't work and gives me an `AtrributeError`.

Comment: Why is this even a class if you just want `k` and `n`?

Comment: Or if you *do* want the instances, why aren't you setting the `k` and `n` attributes in `__init__`?

Comment: You can define a custom `__call__` method in your class and then just do: `print Partition(samplename='Sample1', nS=5)()` The `__call__` could then dispatch off to the `pobject` method

Comment: This is better off as a function, I know, but my requirements say I have to implement as a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `__new__()` to do checks on passed arguments and return various data based on that, not necessarily the instance itself:

```
class Partition(object):

    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        nargin = len(kwargs)
        if nargin == 0:
            return 3, 0
        elif nargin == 2:
            return 0, kwargs["nS"] + 1
        # in other cases return a class instance...
        return super(Partition, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

But at this point you're simulating a factory function by hacking a class behavior. If you want a factory function, make a factory function.